# Firefox printed page skips lines

Tags: firefox, printing, printing-web-page

When printing multi-page webpages in Firefox, one or two lines are lost on each page.  What is the cause of this and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, there was a floating navigation bar on the top of the page that the missing line was printed "under".

The solution was to

1. Right-click the floating navigation bar.
2. Inspect element.
3. Delete the element in Firebug.
4. Print the page again.